# How can I calculate velocity to jump to the target with MatterJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, game-physics, matter.js

I'm trying to create a ball in matter-js that will bounce off rectangles and jump to the next rectangle. All I can know is ball's position and next rectangle's position. I found a [similar question at unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-calculate-force-needed-to-jump-towards-target-point.372288). I tried to implement code from Iron-Warrior's solution in my project, but I have problem that my ball constantly jumps strongly over the next rectangle.

Here is the code that i got:

```
const ball = Bodies.circle(0, 0, 10);

const rectangles = Array(20)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => Bodies.rectangle(i * 140, 200, 20, 20, { isStatic: true }));

Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', (event) => {
  event.pairs.forEach((pair) => {
    if (pair.bodyA === ball) {
      const target = rectangles[rectangles.indexOf(pair.bodyB) + 1];

      const gravity = engine.gravity.y;
      const initialAngle = 60;
      const yOffset = ball.position.y - target.position.y;

      const angle = initialAngle * (Math.PI / 180);

      const distance = Vector.magnitude(Vector.sub(ball.position, target.position));

      const initialVelocity =
        (1 / Math.cos(angle)) *
        Math.sqrt(
          (0.5 * gravity * Math.pow(distance, 2)) / (distance * Math.tan(angle) + yOffset),
        );

      const velocity = {
        x: initialVelocity * Math.cos(angle),
        y: -initialVelocity * Math.sin(angle),
      };

      const angleBetweenObjects = Vector.angle(ball.position, target.position);
      const finalVelocity = Vector.rotate(velocity, angleBetweenObjects);
  
      Body.setVelocity(ball, finalVelocity);        
    }
  });
});

Composite.add(engine.world, [ball, ...rectangles]);
```

Tried to increase `engine.velocityIterations`

Here is codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relaxed-shape-9wy3kt

I believe this is mostly matter-js problem. I tried to change formula, change ball options, rectangle options, nothing helps. Maybe there is some alternative engine to matterjs?

Comment: I don't understand, why do you rotate the `finalVelocity` by the `angleBetweenObjects`? Isn't the formula supposed to get the parabolic trajectory for your chosen angle of 60 degrees?

Comment: @kikon yeah, i think there is no need to rotate velocity. But if i pass just `velocity` to `setVelocity` this doesnt really change the result, the ball still jumping too far. I also found that if i set `engine.velocityIterations`, for example, to 100, then my ball jumps from the first rectangle to the left edge of the second, and then jumps over the third one

Comment: @kikon i edited question, added codesanbox example

Comment: So, the intended behavior is that the ball hits each rectangle?

Comment: @kikon Yes, the ball must jump on each rectangle in turn. Now i have hardcoded rectangles position, but in future i want to make random generation so each rectangle may have different height, width and X and Y positions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally cracked it! The main difficulty was to see the fact that
if you `setVelocity` in the `collisionStart`, the effect of
the collision is still applied to the ball, so its set velocity
was altered, hence the unpredictability of its trajectory.
Thus, the main change is to move the action to `collisionActive`
handler.

There are also some minor additions and corrections to be made
to your code:

- one has to take into consideration the sizes of the bodies, so
  the target shouldn't be the center of the rectangle, but its
  upper surface (`target.bounds.min.y` in this reference system with y increasing downwards) and the center of the ball
  should be `+ball.circleRadius` above that.
- the formula for the initial velocity you were using is not exact, you should replace `distance` by its x component. I used variables `dx` and `dy` (instead of `yOffset`) for the two components of the distance, with which **the formula of the initial velocity needed to throw the `ball` to the `target`** (see for instance [projectile motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion)) might be written as:

  ```js
  dx = target.position.x - ball.position.x
  dy = target.bounds.min.y - ball.position.y - ball.circleRadius
  initialVelocity = dx / Math.cos(angle) * 
      Math.sqrt((0.5 * gravity) / (dy + dx * Math.tan(angle)));
  velocity = Vector.create(
      initialVelocity * Math.cos(angle),  // vx
      -initialVelocity * Math.sin(angle)  // vy
  );
  ```
- the value of the gravitational acceleration in `matter.js` is
  actually `engine.gravity.y * engine.gravity.scale`; that needs to be multiplied by the factor `Body._baseDelta ** 2` where `Body._baseDelta` is the basic time unit of the engine. I derived this correction factor by looking at the source code of `matter.js` and it's a peculiarity (not to say a bug) of this library.
- the air friction should be canceled `ball.airFriction = 0`;
  while taking into consideration the air friction is theoretically
  feasible, that is a much more difficult proposition.
- the angular velocity of the ball should also be set to zero
  `Body.setAngularVelocity(ball, 0)` -- although the spin
  of the ball does not affect its energy, there is a funny
  effect of the rotation, that the ball although touches the
  rectangle in the right position there is no collision and the
  ball somehow slides off the surface.

Here it goes in a code snippet, with some random positioning of the rectangles and a simple reverse of the direction when the ball reaches the last/first rectangle:

```js
const Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Composite = Matter.Composite,
    Vector = Matter.Vector,
    Body = Matter.Body,
    World = Matter.World,
    Events = Matter.Events;

// create an engine
const engine = Engine.create();
//engine.positionIterations = 200;
//engine.velocityIterations = 200;
engine.enableSleeping = true;

const width = 800, height = 300;

// create a renderer
const render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
        width,
        height,
        showAngleIndicator: true,
        showVelocity: true,
    },
});

const ball = Bodies.circle(0, 0, 10);
ball.frictionAir = 0;

let reverse = false;

const intRnd = (min, max) => Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
const rectangles = Array(60)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, i) =>
        Bodies.rectangle(i * 150 + (i === 0 ? 0 : intRnd(-30, 30)), 150 + intRnd(-50, 50), 30, 30, {isStatic: true}),
    );

Events.on(engine, "collisionActive", (event) => {
    event.pairs.forEach((pair) => {
        if (pair.bodyA === ball) {
            let target = rectangles[rectangles.indexOf(pair.bodyB) + (reverse ? -1 : 1)];
            if(!target){
                reverse = !reverse;
                target = rectangles[rectangles.indexOf(pair.bodyB) + (reverse ? -1 : 1)];
            }

            const gravity = engine.gravity.y * engine.gravity.scale * Body._baseDelta * Body._baseDelta;
            const initialAngle = reverse ? -60 : 60;
            const angle = deg2rad(initialAngle);
            const dx = target.position.x - ball.position.x,
                dy = target.bounds.min.y - ball.position.y - ball.circleRadius;
            const initialVelocity = dx / Math.cos(angle) * Math.sqrt((0.5 * gravity) / (dy + dx * Math.tan(angle)));
            if (initialVelocity) {
                const velocity = Vector.create(
                    initialVelocity * Math.cos(angle),
                    -initialVelocity * Math.sin(angle),
                );
                Body.setVelocity(ball, velocity);
            }
            else{
                Runner.stop(runner)
            }
            Body.setAngularVelocity(ball, 0);
        }
    });
});


Composite.add(engine.world, [ball, ...rectangles]);


function deg2rad(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}

// create runner
const runner = Runner.create();

const updateCameraPosition = () => {
    // Calculate camera position based on ball's position - just x

    if (ball.position.y > height * 0.9) {
        stop();
    }
    const xOffset = ball.position.x - width / 2;
    Render.lookAt(render, {
        min: {x: xOffset, y: 0},
        max: {
            x: xOffset + width,
            y: height,
        },
    });
};

Events.on(engine, "afterUpdate", () => {
    updateCameraPosition();
});

const stop = function(){
    Render.stop(render);
    World.clear(engine.world, false);
    Engine.clear(engine);

    document.querySelector('#stop').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);
// run the engine
Runner.run(runner, engine);
// setTimeout(() => {
//     stop()
// }, 300000) // stop after 5min
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js" integrity="sha512-rsntMCBgWYEWKl4HtqWmQ3vdHgvSq8CTtJd19YL7lCtKokLPWt7UEoHVabK1uiNfUdaLit8O090no5BZjcz+bw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<button id='stop' onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

or a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4sx3m8e/).

Comment: Ohh, thanks a lot! I almost got it, but totally forgot about deltaTime, so i thought this solution is wrong. Even thought that the problem might be the mass of the ball, which is always different depending on the radius of the ball. Great job!)